# How to read a compressed (gzip) file without extension in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, gzip

I am new to Spark and have a fun task in hand where I have to read a bunch of files from S3, which have some xml content in them.

These files are compressed (Gzip) but do not have that extension.

I read some questions on this here where people suggest to extend the default codec in Spark and force a different extension.

But in my case, there is no extension and the files are named in some 16 digit UUID format such as `2c7358ca472ad91057da84adfba`.

Comment: Related: There is an [issue on the Spark tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29280) about adding a way to explicitly specify a compression codec when reading files, so Spark doesn't infer it from the file extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [newAPIHadoopFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@newAPIHadoopFile[K,V,F%3C:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](path:String,fClass:Class[F],kClass:Class[K],vClass:Class[V],conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]) (instead of `textFile`) with a custom/modified [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) which forces the use of the `GzipCodec`.

Instead of calling `sparkContext.textFile`,

```scala
// gzip compressed but no .gz extension:
sparkContext.textFile("s3://mybucket/uuid")
```

we can use the underlying `sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile` which allows us to specify how to read the input:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.GzipInputFormatWithoutExtention
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}

sparkContext
  .newAPIHadoopFile(
    "s3://mybucket/uuid",
    classOf[GzipInputFormatWithoutExtention], // This is our custom reader
    classOf[LongWritable],
    classOf[Text],
    new Configuration(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  )
  .map { case (_, text) => text.toString }
```

The usual way of calling `newAPIHadoopFile` would be with `TextInputFormat`. This is the part which wraps how the file is read and where the compression codec is chosen based on the file extension.

Let's call it `GzipInputFormatWithoutExtention` and implement it as follow as an extension of [`TextInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java) (this is a Java file and let's put it in package src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input):

```java
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

public class GzipInputFormatWithoutExtention extends TextInputFormat {

    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split,
        TaskAttemptContext context
    ) {

        String delimiter =
            context.getConfiguration().get("textinputformat.record.delimiter");

        byte[] recordDelimiterBytes = null;
        if (null != delimiter)
            recordDelimiterBytes = delimiter.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

        // Here we use our custom `GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader`
        // instead of `LineRecordReader`:
        return new GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader(recordDelimiterBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return false; // gzip isn't a splittable codec (as opposed to bzip2)
    }
}
```

In fact we have to go one level deeper and also replace the default [`LineRecordReader`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) (Java) with our own (let's call it `GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader`).

As it's quite difficult to inherit from `LineRecordReader`, we can copy `LineRecordReader` (in src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input) and slightly modify (and simplify) the `initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)` method by forcing the usage of the Gzip codec:

(the only changes compared to the original [`LineRecordReader`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) have been given a comment explaining what's happening)

```java
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Seekable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate({"MapReduce", "Pig"})
@InterfaceStability.Evolving
public class GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader.class);
    public static final String MAX_LINE_LENGTH =
            "mapreduce.input.linerecordreader.line.maxlength";

    private long start;
    private long pos;
    private long end;
    private SplitLineReader in;
    private FSDataInputStream fileIn;
    private Seekable filePosition;
    private int maxLineLength;
    private LongWritable key;
    private Text value;
    private boolean isCompressedInput;
    private Decompressor decompressor;
    private byte[] recordDelimiterBytes;

    public GzipWithoutExtentionLineRecordReader(byte[] recordDelimiter) {
        this.recordDelimiterBytes = recordDelimiter;
    }

    public void initialize(
        InputSplit genericSplit,
        TaskAttemptContext context
    ) throws IOException {

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        this.maxLineLength = job.getInt(MAX_LINE_LENGTH, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();
        final Path file = split.getPath();

        // open the file and seek to the start of the split
        final FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        fileIn = fs.open(file);

        // This line is modified to force the use of the GzipCodec:
        // CompressionCodec codec = new CompressionCodecFactory(job).getCodec(file);
        CompressionCodecFactory ccf = new CompressionCodecFactory(job);
        CompressionCodec codec = ccf.getCodecByClassName(GzipCodec.class.getName());

        // This part has been extremely simplified as we don't have to handle
        // all the different codecs:
        isCompressedInput = true;
        decompressor = CodecPool.getDecompressor(codec);
        if (start != 0) {
            throw new IOException(
                "Cannot seek in " + codec.getClass().getSimpleName() + " compressed stream"
            );
        }

        in = new SplitLineReader(
            codec.createInputStream(fileIn, decompressor), job, this.recordDelimiterBytes
        );
        filePosition = fileIn;
        if (start != 0) {
            start += in.readLine(new Text(), 0, maxBytesToConsume(start));
        }
        this.pos = start;
    }

    private int maxBytesToConsume(long pos) {
        return isCompressedInput
                ? Integer.MAX_VALUE
                : (int) Math.max(Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end - pos), maxLineLength);
    }

    private long getFilePosition() throws IOException {
        long retVal;
        if (isCompressedInput && null != filePosition) {
            retVal = filePosition.getPos();
        } else {
            retVal = pos;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private int skipUtfByteOrderMark() throws IOException {
        int newMaxLineLength = (int) Math.min(3L + (long) maxLineLength,
                Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int newSize = in.readLine(value, newMaxLineLength, maxBytesToConsume(pos));
        pos += newSize;
        int textLength = value.getLength();
        byte[] textBytes = value.getBytes();
        if ((textLength >= 3) && (textBytes[0] == (byte)0xEF) &&
                (textBytes[1] == (byte)0xBB) && (textBytes[2] == (byte)0xBF)) {
            LOG.info("Found UTF-8 BOM and skipped it");
            textLength -= 3;
            newSize -= 3;
            if (textLength > 0) {
                textBytes = value.copyBytes();
                value.set(textBytes, 3, textLength);
            } else {
                value.clear();
            }
        }
        return newSize;
    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        if (key == null) {
            key = new LongWritable();
        }
        key.set(pos);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new Text();
        }
        int newSize = 0;
        while (getFilePosition() <= end || in.needAdditionalRecordAfterSplit()) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                newSize = skipUtfByteOrderMark();
            } else {
                newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength, maxBytesToConsume(pos));
                pos += newSize;
            }

            if ((newSize == 0) || (newSize < maxLineLength)) {
                break;
            }

            LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " +
                    (pos - newSize));
        }
        if (newSize == 0) {
            key = null;
            value = null;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        if (start == end) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else {
            return Math.min(1.0f, (getFilePosition() - start) / (float)(end - start));
        }
    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (decompressor != null) {
                CodecPool.returnDecompressor(decompressor);
                decompressor = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```